# How lo overlay shape files in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two shapefiles with geometry polygons. I want to overlay the maps so the boundaries of the second one stay as limits on the first

Here is a notebook with the code and the maps i want to merge:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9YeSHXFuLAvJYMWRyq4wKb41RyHXPz9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this is setting one as a subplot and the other as a boundary with no fill color:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(ncols=1)
ax = df2.plot(edgecolor='yellow')

df.geometry.boundary.plot(color=None,edgecolor='k',linewidth = 2,ax=ax)
```

Comment: After some struggle i could plot the maps.
Tks for the response